drawtext with ffmpeg python
I am trying to add a text to a video using ffmpeg and python.
I tried to do this in the following ways, but it didn't work.
first
(
         ffmpeg
         .input(in_video)
         .filter('drawtext',
                 fontsize=30,
                 fontfile=r"D:\projects\python\editor_bot\downloads\Candara.ttf",
                 text='test test test.',
                 x='if (eq(mod(t\\, 15)\\, 0)\\, rand(0\\, (w-text_w))\\, x)',
                 y='if (eq(mod(t\\, 10)\\, 0)\\, rand(0\\, (h-text_h))\\, y)')
         .output(f'output-final.mp4')
         .run()
 )

second
fil = fr"drawtext=text='test test test':fontsize=30:fontfile=':\projects\python\editor_bot\downloads\Candara.ttf':x='if (eq(mod(t\, 15)\, 0)\, rand(0\, (w-text_w))\, x)':y='if (eq(mod(t\, 10)\, 0)\, rand(0\, (h-text_h))\, y)'"
    (
        ffmpeg
        .input(in_video)
        .output(f'output-final.mkv', filter_complex=fil)
        .run()
    )

But by running this command
ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -filter:v drawtext="fontsize=30:fontfile=candara.ttf:text='testtest test.':x=if(eq(mod(t\,15)\,0)\,rand(0\,(w-text_w))\,x):y=if(eq(mod(t\,10)\,0)\,rand(0\,(h-text_h))\,y)" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 V13.mkv

In the terminal, what I want is done exactly
thanks

what means didn't work? Did you get error? Show full error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Did you get wrong result? Show it in question.

as I remeber ffmpeg-python has function to show command executed on ffmpeg and maybe you could compare it with command which you created - maybe there will be some difference which can explain problem.

.get_args() gives list like ['-f', 'avfoundation', '-framerate', '30', '-pix_fmt', ...] and you can compare it with your working command. See more How to preview the ffmpeg command line while using ffmpeg-python - Stack Overflow

BTW: if you have working command then you can always use subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", "v1.mp4", "-filter:v", ...]) to generate video with text.
